# Points to polygon conversion

Tags: gis, postgis, gdal

I am loading a xml file into my postgresql / postgis database the following field contains cords for lat long of the area im wanting to convert to a polygon. Is there a way to use ST_MPolyFromText to make this work the samples have the long and lat reversed from the order than the way its loading it into the db?

39.43,-80.29 39.46,-80.49 39.43,-80.52 39.46,-80.66 39.98,-80.76 40.07,-80.43 39.46,-79.91 39.39,-80.10 39.40,-80.11 39.39,-80.18 39.43,-80.29

Answer (score 0):

You can format this as WKT quite easily. First, translate your commas to spaces, and spaces to commas, then flip your coordinates from lat,long to long,lat (x,y). Here is a PostGIS function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION polygon_from_funny_format(latlon text) RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$SELECT
    ST_FlipCoordinates(('SRID=4326;POLYGON((' ||
                       translate($1, ', ', ' ,') || '))')::geometry);
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Now you can do:

```
SELECT polygon_from_funny_format('39.43,-80.29 39.46,-80.49 39.43,-80.52 39.46,-80.66 39.98,-80.76 40.07,-80.43 39.46,-79.91 39.39,-80.10 39.40,-80.11 39.39,-80.18 39.43,-80.29');
```

Comment: So if the polygon_from_funny_format are stored in the xfoo column and I executed these query's all I would do is instead of select INSERT INTO the_geom?

Comment: it's worth a try .. this function returns a geometry, so it should go into the_geom. it might only complain if there is something odd with the input, like if the linear ring isn't closed (start/end are the same)

Comment: Basically I'm trying to convert this http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.php?x=0 into postgis if the <cap:polygon> has cords, you have any idea's on how to go about it?

Comment: yeah, you'll need to parse each `entry` from the document somehow, and scrape the attributes you need. This is something that I'd code up in Python. Easier said than done, however.